# R 3.5 for Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, r, rstudio

I am a complete newbie in linux, I got this error:

```
> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘mvtnorm’ is not available
> (for R version 3.4.4)
```

I checked on similar questions, but were for other versions. Do I need to downgrade to ubuntu 16?

If not, how can I upgrade to R3.5, ideally through GUI, or commands that I can copy paste.

Comment: what did you do to get this message? was it in the temrinal? what did you type? no you definitely won't need to owngrade to 16.04 in any event.